# understanding GCC dependency pragma directive

Tags: c, gcc, code-generation, pragma

I was exploring gcc supported pragmas and I just didn't get what the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html) say about `#pragma GCC dependency`:

> `#pragma GCC dependency` allows you to check the relative dates of the current file and another file. If the other file is more recent than the current file, a warning is issued. This is useful if the current file is derived from the other file, and should be regenerated. The other file is searched for using the normal include search path. Optional trailing text can be used to give more information in the warning message.

Can anyone explain this part with some minimal code?

> This is useful if the current file is derived from the other file

How can the current file be derived from the other file? I can understand how another file can be derived form the current file but not *vice versa*.

Comment: Ever heard of lex and yacc?

Comment: Since you understand that one file can be derived from another, what exactly is the conceptual issue with a particular file you happen to be reading having been derived from some particular other one?  Is it just that the concept of [code generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_programming) is new to you?

Comment: I have no clue what is this "code generator" concept nor I'm familiar with lex and yacc. I just thought "deriving" from some file is some sort of copying few lines from file with some file handling functions in c. @JohnBollinger

Comment: @c_nerd, "deriving" in the sense relevant to the pragma carries the implication that if the other file has been modified since the current file was created, then the current file is fundamentally inconsistent.  That could be applicable in a by-hand derivation process, but the main scenario served is when the current (source) file is the output of a program that takes the other file as an input.  `lex` and `yacc` are two classic programs that perform such code generation tasks.

Comment: Working in the world of embedded control, I had more than one time found pixel character definitions written in a specifically formatted text file. A special tool transforms this definition into a C source file. This output file would benefit from the pragma, because if the definition file was changed without running the tool, the C source would be outdated. Hope this real-world example helps, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger for the first part of your comment I created two files, `file.c` and `dependency.c`. I modified the latter one but when I compile `file.c` no warning will be generated( from `#pragma GCC dependency "dependency.c"`)

Comment: @JohnBollinger k that was my dumbness! I saved the `file.c` and then compile it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger   so now I get it when `#pragma GCC dependency" generates warning thanks to you and @the  but still don't understand the use of it. for example we have a source file that gets a file as input and print out its content, if the content of the file changes, when we compile and run the source file it uses the new modified file and not the old one i.e the output will change too. now I don't understand what "regenerating"  the source file in line 3 means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can the current file be derived from the other file? I can
>   understand how another file can be derived form the current file but
>   not *vice versa*.

The primary case served is when a C source file is created by a program, using the designated other file as an input.  The C source is derived from the other file by running the program.  It is to be presumed that differences in the other file would cause the code generator program to produce the C file differently, at least a little, else the pragma in question would not be used.

Thus, if the designated other file's last-modification timestamp is more recent than the C file's, then it is highly suspect to be compiling the C file at all, for it probably does not correspond to the current version of the other file.  Instead, one should regenerate the C source from the other file by running the code generator program again, obtaining a whole new version of the C file to replace the current one.  The new one will, of course, have a last modification timestamp newer than the other file's, because the other file had to exist before the new version of the C file could be generated from it.

*Example:*

There is a classic program named `lex` whose purpose is to help write programs that process text, especially the text of programming languages or rich data languages (the details are not important).  The input file for this program describes how to recognize and categorize the basic units of this language, which are called "tokens".  If the language being parsed were C, then tokens would include language keywords, numeric constants, and operators.  The input file for `lex` is typically tens of lines long.

`lex` reads such an input file and writes a C source file defining several functions and some internal tables that implement the "scanning" behavior required: reading the input text and breaking it up into tokens, which it reports back to its caller.  The C source generated by this program is typically a few thousand lines long, which, compared to the much smaller input file, explains in a nutshell why `lex` is useful.

To build a program that scans the language in question, one provides functions (in a different source file) that call those generated by `lex`, and compiles them along with the `lex`-generated C source to obtain a complete program.  Say the `lex` input file is named `language.l`, and the output of running `lex` on that file is named `language.c`.  If I want to change the behavior of the scanner functions then the thing to do is to modify (small, simple) `language.l` and then re-run `lex` to regenerate `language.c`.

When I change `language.l` in any meaningful way, `language.c` becomes out of date until I generate a new version of it from `language.l` by re-running `lex`.  If I compile the outdated version of `language.c` then the result does not reflect the current version of `language.l`.  This usually constitutes an error on the part of the person building the program, and `#pragma GCC dependency` provides a mechanism for eliciting a warning from the compiler in that situation.

Comment: so the generated c source code from`lex` should include `#pragma GCC dependency "language.l"`? because adding a pragma directive to the generated c source code each time we modify `language.l` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, @c_nerd, it is the generated source code that would carry the `#pragma`.  And no, one would not modify that code by hand after generating it.  Instead, either the code generator would generate such a pragma automatically, or its particular input would contain information that caused it to include the pragma in its output.  Such details are specific to the code generator used.

Comment: thank you so much! although my learning of the problem just begun. way more to go! I'm going to let the question stay unanswered for a few days. @John